# Error when passing comb box value to SQL WHERE

Tags: python, sql, pandas

```
def export(self):
    script = 'WellID,AFEno,AFEsuppno,AccountCode,AFEAmount FROM WellAFEDetails WHERE WellID = ?',(self.wellid_bx.get())
    df = pd.read_sql_query(script, self.con)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter (r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\ExcelOut.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')
    writer.save()
```

The combobox value was 11-21. the error I'm getting is:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '('WellID,AFEno,AFEsuppno,AccountCode,AFEAmount FROM WellAFEDetails WHERE WellID = ?', '11-21')': bytes or integer address expected instead of tuple instance
```

I have also tried

```
(self.wellid_bx.cget('text'))
```

Comment: Did we forget `SELECT` in SQL statement?

Comment: Yeah but same error anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html

First parameter to read_sql_query is first part of your `script` variable. You need to add `SELECT` at the beginning.

Second parameter is self.con, but instead of it, you pass second part of `script` variable `(self.wellid_bx.get())`, which is incorrect.

So execution of method in your situation is wrong.
`(self.wellid_bx.get())` should be passed to read_sql_query as `params`. Please check documentation.

Comment: Good answer, consider showing a full correct line of `read_sql` with all arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this is set up almost exactly like a working export I already created.  The only difference is adding the WHERE and using Pandas.

Comment: Docs: " The syntax used to pass parameters is database driver dependent. Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. Eg. for psycopg2, uses %(name)s so use params={‘name’ : ‘value’}". So it depends, but you can try with:


`df = pd.read_sql_query(script, self.con, params=(self.wellid_bx.get()))`

Comment: I'm using pypyodbc and SQL is for SQL Server. I'm working through it now and  I am getting closer. I tried it and get an error HY00, The SQL Contains 1 parameter marker but 5 were supplied. The 5 is coming from the actual amount of characters in the combo box. For example, if 11-21 is selected it tells me 5 parameters were supplied. If 111TESTA is selected it tells me 8 were supplied.

Comment: Pass a  tuple or list in `params`: `params=(self.wellid_bx.get(),)` or `params=[self.wellid_bx.get()]

Answer (score 0):

With Xyrus's help this is how I was able to get it to work

```
def export(self):
    sql = "SELECT WellID,AFEno,AFEsuppno,AccountCode,AFEAmount FROM WellAFEDetails WHERE WellID = ?"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,self.con, params=([self.wellid_bx.get()]))
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter (r'C:\Users\bjenks\Desktop\ExcelOut.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='bar')
    writer.save()
```